# Iterating Through A Split Index With For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop, split

I have a program in which a user inputs 5 words integers separated with spaces. The program then outputs the characters corresponding to the numbers. eg: `sPaghetti omElette Apple Crouton Exciting` and `2 3 1 1 1` would result in the output of `PEACE`.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("Enter five words: ");
String fiveWords = userInput.nextLine();

// Split string by word
String[] wordIndex = fiveWords.split(" ");


System.out.print("Enter five integers: ");
String fiveInts = userInput.nextLine();

// Split string by integer
String[] intIndex = fiveInts.split(" ");


for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     // Next line doesn't work, though I believe it should
     System.out.println((int) intIndex[i]);
     // Because of previous line, this one shouldn't work
     System.out.println(wordIndex[i].charAt(number));
}
```

When trying to iterate through the index using `charAt()` I keep getting a

```
required: int
found: String
```

error and casting to an int doesn't seem to work. How might I fix this?

Comment: You're looking for [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change at two places:

First is you need to parse the `String` to int with `Integer.parseInt("yourString")` because you can access array with `int` address

Second is to get correct output you need to do `-1` at index because array starts at index `0` like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(intIndex[i]);
    System.out.print(wordIndex[i].charAt(number-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println((int) intIndex[i]);
```

this line of code is throwing error because you are trying to parse String as int primitive which is not allowed.

use `Integer.parseInt(intIndex[i])` to get a Integer object which can be assigned to int priitive through auto unboxing.